# Simple Java 11 JavaFXprogram, Error when run from JAR file (Windows)

Tags: java, javafx, java-11, openjfx

I have a test JavaFX program that runs fine in Eclipse. - I had to add a module-info file (module-info.java) containing the following:

```
module moduletest {
    requires javafx.controls;
    exports com.javafx.test.MenuTest;
}
```

Java class:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MenuTest extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    Scene scene = new Scene(new VBox(), 300, 250);

    Circle circle1 = new Circle(-20,0,200);        
    circle1.setFill(Color.CADETBLUE);
    ((VBox) scene.getRoot()).getChildren().addAll(circle1);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();        
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

When I run it as an exported JAR file using the following command

```
java -jar TonyJavaFX.jar -classpath .;./lib/javafx.controls.jar
```

, I get the following error:

**Error: Could not find or load main class com.javafx.test.MenuTest.MenuTest
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/application/Application**

Note: I have a lib folder directly under the folder I am running the jar from, which contains all the JavaFX jar files.

Comment: In addition to the answer by _nullpointer_, you should be launching your code as a module; use `--module` (or the shorthand version, `-m`) instead of `-jar`. As far as I know, when using `-jar` it doesn't treat the JAR file as a module. This means the `module-info` file is ignored and the system doesn't know to resolve the `javafx.controls` or `javafx.graphics` modules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make sure that the modules `javax.controls` and `javafx-graphics.jar` are present on your *modulepath instead of the classpath*.

```
--module-path ./lib/javafx.controls.jar:./lib/javafx.graphics.jar
```

**Note**: This wouldn't require an addition of `javafx.graphics` module in your module declaration, since it is transitively required by the `javafx.controls` module. Just the presence of the module in the modulepath shall help it.

***Important***: You should ideally be adding the complete lib folder to modulepath. More here - https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#install-javafx

Comment: I still get the same error on adding the graphics.jar.  This is just a test program but yeah agreed I would use module path in "real life" - just trying to get something working.

Comment: @NottmTony How have you created the *.jar* that you're trying to execute? You can follow the documentation link and then follow as mentioned in *Runtime images* => *Modular CLI*

Comment: @NottmTony Its should ideally be a must to be added to *modulepath*. Reason - else it would result in one common unnamed module from where it might not be getting resolved.

Comment: Thanks this worked for me:
    javac --module-path "C:\Program Files\Java\javafx-sdk-11.0.1\lib" --add-modules=javafx.controls  MenuTest.java

Comment: @NottmTony Cool. Do accept as an answer if this could help others as well.

Comment: I decided to build and run at command line and this worked - thanks

BUILD
javac --module-path "C:\Program Files\Java\javafx-sdk-11.0.1\lib" --add-modules=javafx.controls MenuTest

RUN
java --module-path "C:\Program Files\Java\javafx-sdk-11.0.1\lib" --add-modules=javafx.controls MenuTest